# JavaScript get elements from JavaScripted List

Tags: javascript, list

The thing is that I want to make draggable few items from list which is prepared by JavaScript. I always get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null

My list is ready before my function is looking for items in list, I even wrote a break to make sure that list is prepared for making it draggable. In HTML code everything looks fine, list is made properly, so I don't know what is wrong here...

```
<div id="workers" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getWorkers()
    {   
        var dateToView = nv.selectionStart.toString();
        dateToView = dateToView.slice(0, 10);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/GetWorkers",
            data: { date: dateToView },
            success: function (data) {
                var markup = '<ul id="workersList">';
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                {
                    var start = new Date(parseInt(data[i].PlanStart.replace('/Date(', '')));
                    start = start.toLocaleTimeString();
                    var end = new Date(parseInt(data[i].PlanEnd.replace('/Date(', '')));
                    end = end.toLocaleTimeString();
                    markup += '<li data-id="' + data[i].WorkSchedulerID + '"><span style="cursor:move">' + data[i].Username + ' ' + start + ' - ' + end  + '</span></li>';
                }
                markup += '</ul>';
                $('#workers').html(markup);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function makeDraggable() {
        getWorkers();
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("THIS IS");
        }, 2000);
        var parent = document.getElementById("workersList");        
        var items = parent.getElementsByTagName("li");
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var e = items[i];
            var item = {
                element: e,
                id: e.getAttribute("data-id"),
                text: e.innerText,
                duration: e.getAttribute("data-duration"),
                keepElement: true
            };
            DayPilot.Scheduler.makeDraggable(item);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: make sure var parent = document.getElementById("workersList");    returns proper element

Comment: Where do you call `makeDraggable()`? I would expect it after `$('#workers').html(markup);`

Comment: Then `parent` is null if you follow your logic. You sure you're using the right id string or getting elements that exist on the page?

Comment: Are you using jQuery? you used $('#workers').html(markup); if you are using jQuery, then you don't need to add pure JS here. you can write your jQuery selector to access elements. AND if you are not using jQuery, $('#workers').... will fail and your elements will not get added to DOM. this will also result into null assignment to parent

Comment: I think the `makeDraggable` function must be firing before the "workersList" element has been added to the DOM - maybe you need a `setTimeout` in there.

Comment: @RolandStarke you're right, I put `makeDraggable()` after `$('#workers').html(markup);` and now it works. I hate JS...

Comment: @Cezar no need to hate ;). As long as you did not add the element with the id "workersList" to the DOM `document.getElementById("workersList")` can't find anything...